# Identify key in a multiple keys, single lock system

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, raspberry-pi

I have a hobby / office project underway.

We want to issue a key to multiple users each with a different pin pattern. Upon turning the key we want to identify the key and thus the user.

My google fu has so far failed me, does anyone have any ideas for craftinig a solution or a product that could be repurposed?

Comment: You should probably talk to a locksmith. I've never heard of a lock that will *electronically* identify which of the different pin patterns was used to open it. It might be easier to embed an RFID chip into the key's handle, like many cars do.

Comment: We are considering the rfid option, but was hoping for something not wireless. It just seems too easy. :-)

Comment: The other option would be something like a [datakey](http://datakey.com/), where the key is purely electronic (but not wireless), and the mechanical lock is handled by a solenoid. Maxim/Dallas [iButton/1-Wire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IButton) devices would be suitable for this, too.

Answer (score 2):

You will find that multi-keyed locks become ridiculously complex (and expensive) the more keys it is made to accept. And there are practical limits.

An easier, non "wireless" solution would be two factor authentication. Well, an idea similar to it anyway. An electronic keypad lock paired with a regular lock (that cannot be left unlocked if the key is removed). Each person gets a unique keycode, but still requires the physical key to get in.  (Something you know, something you have). Regular key could be copied and the keypad code can be spied on, so it's not foolproof.

Other options are a Mag-Stripe door lock. Easy to make unique cards, but easy to copy as well. Slightly harder to clone are Smart card locks (They have contacts like a SIM card does). Frankly, RFID is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with a conventional lock sounds like quite a tricky project.

Suppose that we can fashion the tumblers out of some reasonably resistive material (yet which is tough enough to endure in that role).  Clearly, multiple keys are accommodated in the lock by means of tumblers that have multiple sections. When the lock is turned successfully, the barrel holds some of the sections, while others remain in the casing. Suppose you could somehow measure the combined series resistance of the tumbler sections which move with the barrel. Or else the sections that are pushed into the casing and remain in place. That could be converted to a code distinguishing the keys.

Another idea is to simply have multiple contacts in the passageway inside the casing, which can detect the extent to which the tumbler sections protrude.

Perhaps only one tumbler guideway needs to have these sensors. The keys just have to be different in the first tumbler. You need to then drill some precise holes through the casing from somewhere, and fashion some kind of contacts that are otherwise electrically isolated from the casing.

[image]

No matter how you look at it, is a project that requires cunning, skill and perhaps some luck (the configuration of parts being suitable for such and such approach).

Comment: It becomes simpler if the action of turning is separated from the action of unlocking the door (via, say, a solenoid). You then don't need to have the tumblers determine if the key is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Hotels have the same problem.
The most common solution I've seen to automated [access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/access_control) at hotels is the [keycard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/keycard) -- a flat plastic card more or less the same size as a credit card,
with some sort of bar code, magnetic stripe, RFID chip, etc. on the card,
and a card reader at each door.

Every card has a unique ID number.
Each card reader is programmed to
identify the card inserted into it and thus the user desiring access,
and optionally log the access attempt.
If that number matches any of the numbers on the list of authorized numbers stored inside that particular card reader,
then the card reader unlocks the door.

As Dave Tweed already pointed out, the [iButton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/iButton) would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

We did some projects like hotel cards, there are some choice, one is use magnetic stripe cards, each reader on the door, encoding different information on the magnetic stripe, there are three tracks, each cards information connected with the reader. the other choice is ID cards, each cards encode a UID number, when the card reader recognize the UID number the door can open it.